# Efficient computation of "variable (number of points included)" moving average in R

Tags: variables, r, performance, moving-average

I'm trying to implement a variable exponential moving average on a time series of intraday data (i.e 10 seconds). By variable, I mean that the size of the window included in the moving average depends on another factor (i.e. volatility). I was thinking of the following:

MA(t)=alpha(t)*price(t) + (1-alpha(t))MA(t-1),

where alpha corresponds for example to a changing volatility index.

In a backtest on huge series (more than 100000) points, this computation causes me "troubles". I have the complete vectors alpha and price, but for the current values of MA I always need the value just calculated before. Thus, so far I do not see a vectorized solution????

Another idea, I had, was trying to directly apply the implemented EMA(..,n=f()) function to every data point, by always having a different value for f(). But I do not find a fast solution neither so far.

Would be very kind if somebody could help me with my problem??? Even other suggestions of how constructing a variable moving average would be great.

Thx a lot in advance
Martin

Comment: I'll add this functionality to the TTR package in the next couple days.

Answer (score 3):

A very efficient moving average operation is also possible via `filter()`:

```
  ## create a weight vector -- this one has equal weights, other schemes possible
  weights <- rep(1/nobs, nobs)     

  ## and apply it as a one-sided moving average calculations, see help(filter)
  movavg <- as.vector(filter(somevector, weights, method="convolution", side=1))
```

That was left-sided only, other choices are possible.

Comment: I'm very grateful for all your hints,

Comment: seeing your names, I know getting help of really experienced R users or even developers...

Comment: Pleasure!  The way to acknowledge around is to a) "vote" on questions you find helpful so you'd click the up-triangle (or down if you disagree strongly enough) and likewise b) to "accept" an answer in case you were the one asking.

Answer (score 0):

For timeseries, see the function `rollmean` in the zoo package.

You actually don't calculate a moving average, but some kind of a weighted cumulative average. A (weighted) moving average would be something like :

```
price <- runif(100,10,1000)
alpha <- rbeta(100,1,0.5)

tp <- embed(price,2)
ta <- embed(alpha,2)

MA1 <- apply(cbind(tp,ta),1,function(x){
    weighted.mean(x[1:2],w=2*x[3:4]/sum(x))
})
```

Make sure you rescale the weights so they sum to the amount of observations.

For your own calculation, you could try something like :

```
MAt <- price*alpha

ma.MAt <- matrix(rep(MAt,each=n),nrow=n)
ma.MAt[upper.tri(ma.MAt)] <- 0

tt1 <- sapply(1:n,function(x){
  tmp <- rev(c(rep(0,n-x),1,cumprod(rev(alpha[1:(x-1)])))[1:n])
  sum(ma.MAt[i,]*tmp)
})
```

This calculates the averages as linear combinations of MAt, with weights defined by the cumulative product of alpha.

On a sidenote : I assumed the index to lie somewhere between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Martin : I implemented your own calculation as well. I misunderstood what you actually wanted to do, hope I understood it now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I just added a `VMA` function to the `TTR` package to do this.  For example:

```
library(quantmod)  # loads TTR
getSymbols("SPY")
SPY$absCMO <- abs(CMO(Cl(SPY),20))/100
SPY$vma <- VMA(Cl(SPY), SPY$absCMO)
chartSeries(SPY,TA="addTA(SPY$vma,on=1,col='blue')")

x <- xts(rnorm(1e6),Sys.time()-1e6:1)
y <- xts(runif(1e6),Sys.time()-1e6:1)
system.time(VMA(x,y))  # < 0.5s on a 2.2Ghz Centrino
```

A couple notes from the documentation:

> ‘VMA’ calculate a variable-length
>   moving average based on the absolute
>   value of ‘w’.  Higher (lower) values
>   of ‘w’ will cause ‘VMA’ to react
>   faster (slower).

The [pre-compiled binaries](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=119) should be on [R-forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org) within 24 hours.